# D3D device in vgasave

Tags: c++, directx

Is it possible to create device/directx application when pc uses vgasave mode?
This is my init function:

```
 d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);    // create the Direct3D interface

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;    // create a struct to hold various device information

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));    // clear out the struct for use
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;    // program windowed, not fullscreen
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D


    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);
```

However when i call later

```
d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);
```

Program crashes, reporting about unhandled violation. Or maybe it isn't about vga, just I'm making something wrong?

---

CreateDevice returns D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE

Comment: Strange question.  An error return does *not* mean "use the pointer anyway".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've filled out way too few parameters in the D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS. You've alomst certainly got bad settings for the back buffer and that kind of thing. If CreateDevice returns D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE, then the d3ddev pointer is NULL, resulting in the access violation when you try to clear the back buffer- since there is no device.

```
D3DDeviceParameters.Windowed = true;
D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferHeight = 0;
D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferWidth = 0;
D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferCount = 1;
D3DDeviceParameters.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
D3DDeviceParameters.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
D3DDeviceParameters.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
D3DDeviceParameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
D3DDeviceParameters.hDeviceWindow = OS->GetHWND();
D3DDeviceParameters.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
D3DDeviceParameters.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24S8;
D3DDeviceParameters.Flags = 0;
D3DDeviceParameters.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;
D3DDeviceParameters.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE; // Vsync.
```

This is my D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS.

Comment: With similar as above, it still returns not available.

Comment: @Neomex: Then you need to find out what devices ARE available. D3D9 can be very fiddly- devices don't need to support all backbuffer formats, for example. You need to use the other methods in the IDirect3D9 interface to discover what devices are available.

Comment: @Neomex: You can't ship a D3DDEVTYPE_REF application. The reference device is only provided by the SDK, not the redist runtime.

Comment: I'll keep this until my graphics card will come back from service, but thanks for info! :)